# NDK Compiler cannot find 'pair' template

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

Trying to integrate https://github.com/evilsocket/arminject into my project and am getting a strange compilation error that doesn't occur when compiling standalone, just within Android Studio. I'm still learning C++ and have reached out to others whom suggested referencing the std namespace but that didn't seem to help either. Any suggestions?

```
C:\Users\TehPirate\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\sources\cxx-stl\system\include\stl_pair.h:86:30: error: no template named 'pair'

This file is included from the following inclusion chain:
C:\Users\TehPirate\AndroidStudioProjects\Pokex\app\src\main\java\com\pirate\pokex\injectors\libhook\main.cpp:1
C:\Users\TehPirate\AndroidStudioProjects\Pokex\app\src\main\java\com\pirate\pokex\injectors\libhook\hook.h:5
C:\Users\TehPirate\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\include\c++\v1\string:505
C:\Users\TehPirate\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\include\c++\v1\string_view:176
C:\Users\TehPirate\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\include\c++\v1\__string:57
C:\Users\TehPirate\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\include\c++\v1\algorithm:643
C:\Users\TehPirate\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\sources\cxx-stl\system\include\utility:36
```

snippet of hoot.h

```
1 #ifndef HOOK_H
2 #define HOOK_H
3
4 #include <android/log.h>
5 #include <string>
6 #include <sys/types.h>
7 #include <dlfcn.h>
8 #include <unistd.h>
9 #include <string>
10 #include <vector>
11 #include "linker.h"
```

snippet of main.cpp

```
1 #include "hook.h"
2 #include "hooks/io.h"
```

snippet of stl_pair.h

```
85 template <class _T1, class _T2>
86 inline bool operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
87 {
88   return __x.first == __y.first && __x.second == __y.second;
89 }
```

Comment: This project has not been updated for 3 years. You need an older NDK version to build it, and it won't work on modern devices.

Comment: @Alex Cohn would you have any recommendations of an alternative? I recently found And hook which might work. ArmInject was ideal for my goal of natively injecting into a running process

Comment: No, I cannot recommend something better. I believe no runtime injection will overcome the strengthened security policies of modern devices. You can add your hooks at build-time, though

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same problem with SDL

Answer (score 0):

The error states no template named 'pair', which is fairly self explanatory. You will need to look at how the template on line 85 is declared and compare it to how it is called

Your issue is on line 86, have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)

Templates are great for creating functions which take data of any type, which is what I assume is going on here

Comment: Went through all the files trying to find `pair` but it doesn't seem to be implicit, are templates kind of anonymous in that I need to instead look for `<class _T1, class _T2>` reference? I'm use to OO

Comment: I assume line 86 is trying to call http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

you are then trying to pass template values, into the pair template. But by the looks of the error it is not finding the pair template at all

Answer (score 0):

This same problem actually occured with me. But, after replacing `pair` with `std::pair` inside the stl_pair.h solved the problem.

But the problem is not quite solved. Because there are alot of errors occuring within these c++ core files.

From this I conclude that. The NDK version itself has bugs.

Try using another versions of NDK